# Unable to declare to use C++11 in CLion

Tags: c++11, clion

For hours I'm trying to declare to use C++11 in CLion without any effects. Still CLion shows me undefined functions name that actually exist, but in C++11:

[image]
.

My CMakeLists.txt files looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Program)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

add_executable(program src/program.cpp)
```

How am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you including the correct header file? And is it a problem only with CLion? Does it actually *build* without errors?

Comment: As an unrelated note, don't use command-line arguments unless you actually *know* they have been provided. Check `argc` first, or you might use a null pointer or go out of bounds of `argv`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I don't use CLion to build the program. I use it as an editor. My headers looks like: https://www.screencast.com/t/ad86VThz

Comment: @Some programmer dude I'm building the program by the command: `g++ -std=c++11 -o ../program program.cpp -pthread -lcurl -lcpp_redis -static-libstdc++`

Comment: I seem to recall a similar problem I had with some version of CLion last year. It's just a false positive and nothing to worry about. As long as the code builds it's not a problem (even through it is irritating). Can't replicate it with my current (EAP) version though.